# Touchpad not working at all in ubuntu 14.04lts

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I am new to the ubuntu.my touchpad worked normally when i installed the ubuntu.But after while it stopped working abruptly.I can also able to external mouse.

here is my xinput list

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera                        id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

My kernal is

> Linux nithya-Satellite-C850 4.2.0-18-generic #22~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri >Nov 6 22:20:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

so please help to make the touchpad working.

Comment: What is the laptop model? What is the kernel version `uname -a`. Please [edit] your question and add this information TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: You added only kernel version? What is your laptop model?

Comment: toshiba-satellite-c850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely support of your touchpad has been added to new linux kernels.
You can update the kernel by running in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Then reboot and try the touchpad.

Comment: still not working .now my kernel version shows as Linux nithya-Satellite-C850 4.2.0-18-generic #22~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 22:20:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  @Pilot6

Comment: The touchpad is probably not supported yet.

Comment: can you give any other suggestions?

Comment: In this case I would report a bug, or program a kernel fix. There is no easy solution I am afraid.

Comment: now my touchpad works

Comment: after proper rebooting